# Geth on Windows Closed Itself

Tags: go-ethereum

i rented a windows 2012 vps and install both mistwallet and geth. Mistwallet is working great.. but geth in other hand... it closed iself right after i double click it... can anyone tell me what wrong? or i lack certain supporting files?

for references i install geth windows from this link https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click on geth.exe and it has an error it will probably close the window directly. So I recommend you to open it via a cmd-window. Then you should see if there's an error-message.

1. start a cmd -> Windows+R and then type cmd
2. Change to your Geth directory -> cd 'C:\Program Files\Geth'
3. start Geth with [parameters](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) or console -> geth.exe ...

Comment: Hai... ty so much... at first it show "failed to start ledger hub" .. but then after a few moment it start imported blocks... so i guess it is working already?

Comment: yes, the ledger hub error is kind of normal. I've got that one too